# Certificates for samba share

Tags: windows, samba, certificate, share

As far as I understand Windows shares use the samba protocol?
Is there any non-password version where you use some kind of key/certificate?
Thinking of something like the authorized keys in Linux ssh.

What I want to have is the "net use z: \server\path" but without using a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is only possible in two scenarios:

- Domain environment: your computer and the file server must be members of the same domain (let's just skip domain trusts for sake of brevity) and you must be logged in to your computer with a domain user account; also, your domain user account needs proper access rights on the target file share.
- Non-domain environment: your computer and the file server must be in the same workgroup and the file server must have a local user account with the same username and password as the one you are using on your computer; also, the local user account on the file server needs proper access rights on the target file share.

If no one of these contidions are met, you'll need to provide a username and a password; it's not possible to authenticate against Windows file shares using certificates or SSH keys.

Comment: Hmm, there is an AD in place that protects the file server, but the machine is using a local user. So you mean there is no way to tell it to use the AD-user and make it not pasword-based?

Comment: If you wonder, it's a build slave that needs to access some files during the build process. Our password policy is pretty strict, so we don't want to update the build slave every 60 days because the AD-user got a new password.

Comment: The only way to have automatic (passwordless) authentication between different servers in an AD domain is to use a domain user account; since this is clearly a service account used by an automated process, you can and should ask your domain administrator(s) to set its password to never expire. This is standard practice for service accounts.

Comment: this is sooo sad, let's see if we can figure something out, Thank you!

Comment: This is not "sad", it's conforming to specifications. Specifications for an Active Directory domain require a centralized user account database and provide Single-Sign-On, all the user accounts in AD are automatically recognized across all domain computers, without requiring re-authentication. This is by design. Password expiration is also by design, but it can be bypassed for service accounts, which are used for automated tasks and not constantly moniored by actual users who can change their password.

Comment: For me it's sad, after being free of windows for 15 years, the first time I run into a problem I cannot fix it. Or at least not the way I thought would be most logical. :-)

Comment: Just stumbeled over this, sounds a little like what I was thinking of? Do you know if it would work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857580/certificate-based-authentication-to-file-share

Comment: If you read that question, you'll see there is only one answer and it suggests using Kerberos, which is a core part of domain authentication. This is still relying on AD. Certificate-based authentication to SMB shares is something I've never heard of in the Windows world and I'm quite sure it's not possible at all.

Comment: Awesome, saves me a lot of time then! Thank you again!

Comment: Domain environment: your computer and the file server must be members of the same domain (let's just skip domain trusts for sake of brevity) and you must be logged in to your computer with a domain user account; also, your domain user account needs proper access rights on the target file share.